# Tracking events on multiple google analytics accounts in android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to track app events and activity sessions on multiple google analytics accounts in android. Is this possible. if yes then how can i achieve that.

Comment: Hi Akash, as this is Stack Overflow, you will need to provide some demonstrations of what you have attempted, like sample code, what resources you have researched and tried out. Please add those details and someone may be able to assist you better.

Comment: Why do you want multiple account to do the same?

Comment: While you are creating tracker using the tacker id, there you can pass different id and get more than objects to send the data to GA. I'm not sure about this,but you can give a try.

Comment: @BiplabDe i have to give access of analytics to my client currently anaytics is on my personal account.. so i m looking for option to add multiple tracking id so client as well as i can track the event..

Comment: @BiplabDe thanks.. i will try create multiple tracker..